# PyDev Outline is not showing my current cursor location

Tags: eclipse, pydev

Is it possible for the Outline view in PyDev to automatically select the element where my cursor is currently located? Currently, the selected element of the Outline view does not follow my cursor position. This would be enormously helpful, since I'm working with files of 3000 lines or more!

The only workaround I've found so far is pressing Ctrl+O to bring up the so-called "Quick Outline." This window will show my current position in the outline. But this is, as I said, only a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it! The option is called "Link With Editor," and it's available via the "View Menu" next to the Outline tab.